# Search for a file in directory by it's name (without knowing extension)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, directory, fs

I want to find a file in a specific directory by it's name and without knowing it's extension

```
app.get("/test/:id", (req, res) => {
    const mongo_id = req.params.id;
    const file_path = __dirname + somepath + mongo_id + ".png"; // I should remove this extension but how to find file ?
    if (!existsSync(file_path)) return res.status(404).end() ; // Check if file exists

    res.sendFile(file_path) ;
})
```

As you see I am adding  `.png` at the end of the path that I want to send it as a response but sometimes I want to save some files that they are not PNG file

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by saving file extension during saving file information into the database

And when I send request for getting image response I get the file extension and necessary information for finding it in the goal directory and send the file into the response .
Here's my code :

```
app.get("test/:id", (req, res) => {
    const mongo_id = req.params.id;

    MyModel.findById(mongo_id, (err, file) => {
        if (err || !file) return res.status(404).end()

        const file_path = __dirname + somepath + mongo_id + '.' + file.extension;
        
        if (!existsSync(file_path)) return res.status(404).end();
        res.sendFile(file_path);
    })
})
```

But if anyone knows a solution that I mentioned in my question I would also appreciate it if they shared it .